# $y$-intercept of a line given an equation in polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

The graph of
$r = \frac {-5}{2 \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)}$
is a line. Find the $y$-intercept of this line.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a hint**: If you have the slope-intercept form $y=mx+b$, you can substitute $y=r\sin\theta$ and $x=r\cos\theta$ to get $r\sin\theta=m(r\cos\theta)+b$, and then solving for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ gives $r=\frac{b}{\sin\theta-m\cos\theta}$.

More generally, if the line has equation $ax+by=c$, you can solve for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ to get $r=\frac{c}{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta}$.

Comment: So, the y-intercept would be -5?

Comment: Yes, you are right.